# Magento 2 How to get Customer address after registration?

Tags: customer, customer-attribute, customer-address, magento2.3.1

How to get customer address(company,telephone,country,state,city etc.) after registration in observer?

I am using observer.

Code -

```
$customer = $observer->getData('customer');
```

first name and email is working -

```
$customer->getFirstName()
$customer->getEmail()
```

Below code is not working -

```
$customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getCompany()
$customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getTelephone()
$customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getCountry()
$customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getRegion()
$customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getCity()
```

Comment: Kindly mention your event?

Comment: customer_register_success

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `$customer`  is an object of service contact data interface `\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface` .So you cannot get default address using `$customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()`.

This `CustomerInterface` does not have  any method like `getDefaultShippingAddress()` which give default address.

If you want to get default from   `$customer` then you can use `$customer->getAddresses()` but its give list of address of that customer. So, you need **run a `foreach loop` for getting default address**.

```
 if ($customer instanceof \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface) {
        $addresses = $customer->getAddresses();

        foreach ($addresses as $address) {
            if ($address->isDefaultShipping()) {
                // Default Shipping Address
                $address->getCompany();
                $address->getTelephone();
                $address->getCountryId();
                $region = $address->getRegion();
                if($region !== null && ($region instanceof \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface)){
                     $region->getRegionCode();
                     $region->getRegionId();
                     $region->getRegion();
                }
                $address->getCity();
            }
            if ($address->isDefaultBilling()) {
                // Default Shipping Address
                $address->getCompany();
                $address->getTelephone();
                $address->getCountryId();
                $region = $address->getRegion();
                if($region !== null && ($region instanceof \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\RegionInterface)){
                     $region->getRegionCode();
                     $region->getRegionId();
                     $region->getRegion();
                }
                $address->getCity();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address::getDefaultShipping()

Comment: wrong method was there. Now it fix

Comment: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Address::getCountry()

Comment: Modified... it is working

Comment: before mail is not coming,now mail receive but with error - Error filtering template: Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Region could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/gbdistro_new/vendor/magento/framework/Filter/Template.php on line 173

Comment: everything is going perfect now but only 1 issue "Recoverable Error: Object "

Comment: works perfect to me on customer_register_success 2.3.5